# jquery.get() problems with IE8

Tags: jquery, debugging, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to fix a supposed bug in javascript for IE8 and here are the steps I tried:

1. Checked in chrome/firefox(mac and win) to see if it also happens there. result: it only happens in IE8
2. tried to reproduce the bug by following steps from client. Bug "appeared" in IE8.

Bug was a div not showing and a javascript error sprouting up. I looked at the error and saw this:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
Timestamp: Fri, 28 Jan 2011 07:32:46 UTC

Message: Syntax error
Line: 70935353
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://edge.foo.dev:3000/

Message: Syntax error
Line: 70935353
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://edge.foo.dev:3000/
```

okay not very helpful at all right? I tried to use firebug light to check where the problem could lie and now there are no errors...but my dynamic div still isn't showing.

The jquery stuff I'm using is just an ajax call and a callback after data loads that displays that data. Is there another way of pinpointing where exactly the error is happening? For now I'll be adding alerts after every line of code but that will be tedious to debug.

*EDIT* 
I do get a response from the server and it is not an error. It is a 200 response ok so i guess the problem lies in appending/displaying the result? Or during callback?

I'm guessing its the plugin im using: http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/live-search/

unless anyone can point out I'm using a buggy jquery function/logic in my code.

*EDIT 2*

Ok I am checking the plugin out and pinpointed it to this:

```
jQuery.get(config.url + q, function (data) {
})
```

I get the data(in firebug lite and alert also prints it out nicely) BUT

```
liveSearch.html(data); this FAILS
showLiveSearch(); // this just shows the div
```

compared to this:

```
liveSearch.html("<ul><li>blah blah blah</li></ul>"); this SUCCEEDS in showing the div but the error is still there(i can live with that, as long as it shows the results)
showLiveSearch(); // this just shows the div
```

I tried data.toString() but it still doesn't show me the html snippet the server throws back at it.

Comment: that is impressive coding - 70M+ lines of code in one file

Comment: @Prescott: must be because of jquery's include? My application.js is 350 lines long, that's why I'm having a hard time pinpointing the problem

Comment: @yoda: added code that I think is responsible for the error

Comment: Did you try using the built in script debugging tools for IE8?  They are pretty good.  You can set breakpoints, watches, conditional breakpoints, can step back through the stack at any point, ..etc.  Also could post a data sample?  A lot of times the syntax error is caused by not properly escaping a quotation or apostrophe

Comment: @Aliester: yup i did, it's not that helpful when the line number is 212 million -_-

Comment: edited the question to reflect my current findings :)

Comment: Aliester did it, apparently it was really broken html that did it that's why .html() didn't append it. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: Copied the relevant part of my comment into an answer.  Thanks (=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of times the syntax error is caused by not properly escaping a quotation or apostrophe in the data you are trying to append. Also consider that the data you're trying to append might have broken HTML which will break in IE(ul's have divs outside lis, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and wanted to share for posterity what worked for me. I changed my call from

`$.get("mypage.htm?data1=foo&data2=bar", function(data){alert(data);});`

to this

`$.get("mypage.htm", {data1:"foo", data2:"bar"}, function(data){alert(data);});`

And IE8 liked it fine.

Comment: the second one is what it should actually be. passing the data via url like that isn't recommended